# Terminate subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.7

I have a wrapper script, inside that there are many other test script. Inside of one of the test script I make a subprocess using Popen class. The problem is that I don't know how to terminate that child process and return to main process and continue with the next test script. My wrapper stops at the test script that has the child process and never continue. Can you give a hint? Thx.
P.S. kill() or terminate() or anyother function that I consider usefull, doesn't put me back to the main process. I want to terminate the subprocess and continue with the main process.

Comment: How do you mean .terminate() doesn't continue the main process?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the child in the main script. With that reference call the `terminate()`

```
from subprocess import Popen

class TestApp(object):
    app = None

    def start(self):
        self.app = Popen(['your command'])

    def stop(self):
        self.app.terminate()
```

In the main script:

```
app1 = TestApp()
app1.start()
app2 = TestApp()
app2.start()
#do something here
app1.stop()
app2.stop()
#do more here
```